# From a spring maven application to a springboot application

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, maven, configuration

I have an already build and running maven spring application with the required configuration xml files put in the webapp and Web-Inf folders, I usually compile it and take the war to run it on a locale tomcat server. now I want to use springboot .

I added the needed dependencies, main class and application.properties, I imported the xml files using @ImportResource but I still get an unexpected 404 page.